# What is the stable range for orbit of the Earth?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, solar-system, celestial-mechanics

Suppose a force pushes/pulls Earth straightly toward Sun and make earth x kilometers closer/farther from Sun. For what x the Earth remains in a stable orbit, rather than spirally fall to the Sun or going farther away? What math is involved?

Comment: Gravitational orbits never spiral into or away from the Sun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Sun-Earth system alone, the important quantity here is the [effective gravitational potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_potential#Example:_gravitational_potential) 
$$
U_{eff}=\frac{\ell^2}{2mr^2}-\frac{GmM}{r}
$$
with $m$ the mass of Earth and $M$ the mass of the Sun, and $\ell$ is the angular momentum of the Earth about the Sun.  Since the orbit of the Earth is basically circular we can take $r$ to be 
$r=R_0=149600\times 10^6m$ to be the average distance to the Sun, and estimate
$$
\ell=m v r= m \times 29.78\times 10^3 \times R_0 \approx 2.66\times 10^{37}
$$
The energy scale $U_0$ can be set using $U_0=\vert U_{eff}(r=R_0)\vert $, so that plotting
$U_{eff}/U_0$ as a function of $\rho=r/R_0$ gives the graph below.

[image]

The minimum of this potential, which is the radius where the orbit is circular, of course occurs at $\rho=1$ and $U_{eff}/U_0=-1$.  If you "push" the Earth a bit towards the Sun, the Earth will oscillate about two radial turning points that will define the minimum and maximum radius of the elliptical orbits.  For instance, if you push the Earth (keeping $\ell$ constant) so that $U_{eff}/U_0=-3/4$, the radius would oscillate between $\rho_{min}\approx 0.67$ and $\rho_{max}\approx 2.0$.

The orbit remains bound as long at the total energy remains negative.  You can reach the threshold $\rho_{c}$ by solving for $\rho$ when you set $U_{eff}=0$.  This gives $\rho_{c}\approx 1/2$.  Thus, if you pushed the Earth to a radius smaller than one half of it's current average radius (managing $v$ so that $\ell$ would remain constant), the orbit would become unbound.

Comment: Dear ZeroTheHero, thanks. Can you give me an explicit formula to show that if f(r)<$v_0$<g(r) a closed orbit will be formed?

Comment: The condition is on the energy, which depends on velocity *and* position, not on velocity alone.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't dependent on the distance only but also the velocity, if you are thinking purely in terms of gravitational attraction. For example, the earth will fall right into the sun if it had zero tangential velocity right now. For every distance, you can get a velocity for a stable orbit.

That is until you start thinking about other forces such as tidal forces and drag which will become important at small distances(relatively speaking).

Answer (score 0):

Are we considering only the Earth and the Sun?  No other bodies?

If so then orbits are quite stable.  Even quite a large perturbation will not not cause the Earth to spiral into the Sun.  With classical mechanics and Newton's laws, there are no spiral orbits.  There are only conic sections: circles, ellipses, and hyperbolas.  The Earth's orbit is already not quite circular, a small perturbation would just change it to another ellipse, maybe more eccentric maybe less.  A larger perturbation might make the orbit so eccentric that it approaches the Sun very closely but provided that it does not actually collide then it should still continue to orbit.  Consider comets which spend most of their life far from the Sun but occasionally approach closely.  If the Earth comes too close without colliding then tidal forces might rip it apart.  Another possibility, with a very large perturbation is that the Earth achieves escape velocity from the Sun and enters a parabolic or hyperbolic orbit and never returns.

If there are other bodies, e.g. Jupiter, then it gets more complex as even Newton's laws cannot be analytically solved.  Nonetheless, provided we don't experience a close encounter with one of the other planets, the above should still be close.

For spiral orbits, you would need to go beyond classical mechanics and Newton.  I think that if you get too close to a black hole, this could happen but that is beyond me.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still not getting it. Let me ask a simpler question: A small object is at the distant r from the Sun with an initial velocity of $v_0$ tangent to the circle with radius r and the Sun as the center. What are the different scenarios for the orbit of object?

Comment: Staying in the realm of classical mechanics and Newton and not coming too close to each other or other things, the possible orbits are: circle, ellipse, parabola, and hyperbola.  The first two are closed and will repeat (of course, the circle is just a special case of the ellipse).  The other two will escape the Sun.  I am not saying that this is obvious but it is the result of mathematical analysis of Newton's laws.  If you come too close then tidal forces may destroy the object, atmospheric drag, or a collision could occur.  With three or more bodies, a general solution is not possible.

Comment: Okay thanks. Now the question is, for what values of $v_0$ we will get a closed orbit?

Comment: ZeroTheHero has addressed that.  Roughly, you want to achieve escape velocity from the Sun.  I forget the value but it is easy to Google.  Similar to escaping the Earth: throw a stone fast enough and it will never come down.  Merely give it more kinetic energy than its potential energy (with the convention of zero at infinity).  I am ignoring air resistance which would defeat this.

Comment: Also look up the Roche Limit.  This deals with the case of coming so close that tidal forces rip the Earth apart.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roche_limit.

Comment: I want a formula to show that if f(r)<$v_0$<g(r) a closed orbit will be formed.

Comment: ZeroTheHero has given you that.  I hinted at it with my mention of escape velocity.  You need a kinetic energy greater than the potential energy so that the Sun cannot capture it.  If it is initially approaching with this high kinetic energy then it will, of course, get even faster but, provided that it does not collide, it will pass and never come back.  As it recedes, it will slow but never stop.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers and comments have cleared up your misconceptions but it remains that "What is the stable range for orbit of the Earth?" can be a legit question. The meaning given to it by astronomers is usually: are there orbits leading to either an ejection from the solar system, or to collisions with other planets (or the Sun)? and the followup: how close is our current orbit to one of those troublesome orbits? There is an excellent [article](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Stability_of_the_solar_system) by Jacques Laskar, one of the specialist in this field. One of the problem, of course, is that the solar system is chaotic: a change of 15 m in the position of the Earth today would make it impossible to predict where the orbit of the Earth would be in about 100 million years.