# Range of velocity needed to stay in an orbit of the Sun

Tags: orbital-motion

This is not a homework. It's motivated by this question: [What is the stable range for orbit of the Earth?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/354872/what-is-the-stable-range-for-orbit-of-the-earth)

Suppose a small particle is at the distance r from the Sun and the velocity vector v is tangent to the circle with the radius r around the Sun. If we keep r constant, for what values of v the path will be an orbit?

Comment: If r is constant your orbit is circular? Independent of v? And sorry, I'm not very familiar with angular momentum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Kepler problem, circular orbits have a velocity given by
$$v=\sqrt{\frac{G M}{r}}.$$

Hence for any given $r$, there is precisely one velocity which would correspond to a circular orbit.  If you have a different velocity, your orbit could either be elliptical, parabolic, or hyperbolic.  The way to find out if your orbit is bound or not, is by looking at the specific orbital energy equation:
$$E=\frac{v^2}{2} - \frac{GM}{r}.$$
If $E<0$, the orbit is bound.  If $E=0$, the orbit is unbound and parabolic.  If $E>0$, the orbit is unbound and hyperbolic.  Hence if you have a given $r$, your particle will be in a bound orbit if 
$$v < \sqrt{\frac{2 GM }{r}}.$$

Comment: Hmm, is the dimension of $v^2/2$ as energy?

Comment: @Asmani This is specific orbital energy, so it means we've divided out the mass dependence, and is hence valid for any particle regardless of its mass.  This is a trick often employed in celestial mechanics, where you'll also encounter specific angular momentum $\vec{h}$, which is the angular momentum, per unit mass.  If you want actual energy, multiply through by the mass of your particle. Good spot though!